# What does date and month mean in profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

What does date and month mean in profile data? It shows 29 months 10 week 9 days.

Although I am less than an year old user.

Comment: Can you add a image of what you are looking at? All I see is "Member for 2 months" in your profile.

Comment: I am older than that, I joined before December

Comment: Can you add an image please?

Comment: Sorry adding picture is really tough for me. On left down most corner, its written.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Which profile are you talking about? Your SO profile? Your MSE profile? Your overall network profile? Add a link to your question. Also, by what means are you accessing the site?  The app? If so, iOS or Android? The mobile site? Which browser? The full desktop site? What browser and version? We need details in order to help you. And bear in mind that what *you* see in your profile is by default different from what *others* see.

Comment: Its written in vote cast section

Comment: @AnubhavGoel That doesn't help too much. Please answer all the questions I just asked you (yep, all of them). And make sure to answer by [edit]ing your question, not by adding more comments.

Comment: Physics stack site. Saw it using opera mini. Android. Full desktop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As can be seen in your [Physics.SE profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/96487/anubhav-goel?tab=topactivity), this is the total amount of votes you have cast in the last month, week, and day:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for help. I am so silly , couldn't figure it.

Comment: It's not 100% obvious for those who never seen it before, I'll give you that. :)

Comment: This is why an image could be helpful in this case....